# ReactiveCocoa after catch the error, the button signal not get triggered again

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, reactive-cocoa

If I add a `UIControlEventTouchUpInside` signal to a `doneButton`, and call an API, if the API fails, the catch will be called. But if I try to click the button again, the button control event does not get triggered.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [[[[[self.doneButton rac_signalForControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside] doNext:^(id x) {
        [SVProgressHUD show];
    }] flattenMap:^RACStream *(id value) {
        return [[HttpService sharedService] updateImageData:UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self.signatureImageView.image, 0.5)];
    }] catch:^RACSignal *(NSError *error) {
        [SVProgressHUD showErrorWithStatus:error.localizedDescription];
        return [RACSignal empty];
    }] subscribeNext:^(id x) {
        [SVProgressHUD dismiss];
        [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    }];
}
```

Comment: Please check my answer.

Answer (score 2):

I think this thread will help. https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa/issues/1218

A signal will automatically be unsubscribed to if it fails / errors.  You can use `- retry`, however that will simply keep trying your operation until is doesn't fail, which, if there is a perpetual issue will just loop indefinitely.

Wrapping this condition in a `flattenMap` will capture the issue without unsubscribing the initial `rac_signalForControlEvents` observation.

See **mdiep**s comment in the thread above on GitHub, and maybe do something like.

```
[[[[self.doneButton rac_signalForControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside] doNext:^(id x) {
    [SVProgressHUD show];
}] flattenMap:^RACStream *(id value) {
    return [[[HttpService sharedService] updateImageData:UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self.signatureImageView.image, 0.5)] 
      catch:^RACSignal *(NSError *error) {
        [SVProgressHUD showErrorWithStatus:error.localizedDescription];
        return [RACSignal empty];
      }];
}] subscribeNext:^(id x) {
    [SVProgressHUD dismiss];
    [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}];
```

I've not actually constructed a test with this code.  Just guessing based on what you might have in your `HttpService` Class.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `RACCommand` to solve this problem.

```
RACCommand *doneCommand =
[[RACCommand alloc] initWithSignalBlock:^RACSignal *(NSString *selected) {

    return  [[[self updateImageSignal]
              doCompleted:^{
                  [SVProgressHUD dismiss];
                  [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
              }] doError:^(NSError *error) {
                  [SVProgressHUD showErrorWithStatus:error.localizedDescription];
              }];
}];

self.doneButton.rac_command = doneCommand;
```

Now create `RACSignal` that send success and error according to your request.

```
-(RACSignal *)updateImageSignal {
@weakify(self)
return [RACSignal createSignal:^RACDisposable *(id<RACSubscriber> subscriber) {
    @strongify(self)
    [[HttpService sharedService] updateImageData:UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self.signatureImageView.image, 0.5)
                                        complete:^(BOOL success) {
                                            if(success)
                                                [subscriber sendNext:@(success)];
                                            else
                                                [subscriber sendError:nil];
                                            [subscriber sendCompleted];
                                        }];
    return nil;
}];
}
```

Hope it will help you. And If you have any question then feel free to ask.